# Subscription Page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

I have a registration page I  am sending an email from asp.net ,one mail to the registered user and other mail to the admin that too with different body...Ho can I achieve this? Also, User should give a confirmation link saying that you have subscribed and when the user clicks on the mail given link , a mail should fire to the admin saying that This User has been Registered.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Yes I tried to look into To attribute but could not figure out when in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code is used to send mail in aspx.cs page,make a try.if yo are using asp.net with c#

in aspx
         `<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxMark1" runat="server" />`

```
CheckBox Ckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxMark1");
       if (Ckbox.Checked == true)
       {

           sendMail(toemail);
           //other code
      }
  public void sendMail(String toemail)
{

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(toemail);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Subject";

        mail.Body = "  Your Contents in the mail";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "Password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: I already dis this Can you temme how shud I sent one mail to 2 different persons with different body

Comment: You can use checkBox to send One mail to different persons,Did you tried anything regarding the code?

Comment: where shud i put the chkbox

Comment: Put the checkbox in the aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, Send the from address and body details by yourself .

```
public void SendMail(string FromEmail, string Subject, string Body)
    {
        string ToEmail="YourAdmin@Gmail.com";
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage eMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        eMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail);
        eMail.To.Add(ToEmail);
        eMail.Subject = Subject;
        eMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        eMail.Body = Body;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SMTP = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(); 
       SMTP.Send(eMail);     
        eMail.Dispose();
    }
```

**Web.Config:**

```
 <system.net>
 <mailSettings> 
<smtp> 
<network host="your stmp server" port="25" userName="your from email" password="your password"/> 
</smtp> 
</mailSettings> 
</system.net>
```

> Should be you have mail hosting server .

and if you want to send mail without page postback , See my  [little bit blog](http://dotnet--solutions.blogspot.in/2013/03/send-mail-without-page-post-back-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/08/create-registration-form-and-send.html

You can use this link to achive the activation for user. But for sending mail to the admin, Use simple send email method.